# Why do privileges have different reputation requirements on other SE sites?

Tags: support, reputation

I just noticed that the reputation requirements for privileges are [higher on gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges) than [on rpg.stackexchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/privileges). For example, Create Tags is 150 here, but 300 on Gaming, and Trusted User is 4,000 here but 20,000 on Gaming.

What's the difference? (Beta status? User count? Age?)

Can reputation requirements for privileges increase? If they do, can you lose privileges already accrued?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are still in public beta, it has different (lower) rep requirements for privilege levels.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) post on MSO for more information.

Comment: came here to say this

Comment: and yes, when a site goes from beta to live, if you have enough rep for the privilege on beta, but not enough for the privilege on the live site, you will temporarily lose those privileges (e.g. with 250 rep, you'll be unable to create tags again until you break 300).